# Помогите разобраться с условием в запросе activerecord

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

У меня есть для поиска несколько параметров, включая `dropDownList`.

Пример:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'maincatalog')->dropDownList($maincatalog, ["prompt" => Yii::t('app', 'select_cat')])->label(false) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'listproduct')->dropDownList($listproduct, ["prompt" => Yii::t('app', 'select_cat')])->label(false) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'q')->textInput(['class' => 'input'])->label('')?>


$query = Addproduct::find()
                     ->where(['catalog' => $maincatalog])
                     ->andWhere(['product' => $listproduct])
                     ->andWhere(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();
```

Если `$maincatalog` не выбрана, то `$maincatalog` не имеет значение, из-за этого запрос не работает, то есть выдает null, но если поставить условия их очень много.
Как можно игнорировать `where(['catalog' => $maincatalog])` если `$maincatalog` хранит пустое значение?

```
 $query = Addproduct::find();

if ($maincatalog != NULL)
    $query->where(['catalog' => $maincatalog]);

if ($listproduct != NULL)
    $query->andWhere(['product' => $listproduct]);


$query->andWhere(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();
```

этот код не работает, почему?

понимаете, условие if if( $maincatalog != NULL ) могут иметь много комбинации, из-за этого у меня получается много условии типа так

```
if($maincatalog == "" && $listproduct == "" && $q == ""){
  $query = "all empty";
} elseif($maincatalog == "" && $listproduct != "" && $q == ""){
  $query = Addproduct::find()->where(['product' => $listproduct])
    ->andWhere(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();
} elseif($maincatalog != "" && $listproduct == "" && $q == "") {
  $query = Addproduct::find()->where(['catalog' => $maincatalog])
    ->andWhere(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();
} elseif($maincatalog == "" && $listproduct == "" && $q != "") {
    $query = Addproduct::find()->where(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();
} elseif($maincatalog == "" && $listproduct != "" && $q != "") {
    $query = Addproduct::find()->where(['product' => $listproduct])
       ->andWhere(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();
} elseif($maincatalog != "" && $listproduct == "" && $q != "") {
   $query = Addproduct::find()->where(['catalog' => $maincatalog])
      ->andWhere(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();
} else {
    $query = Addproduct::find()->where(['catalog' => $maincatalog])
     ->andWhere(['product' => $listproduct])->andWhere(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();
}
```

в дальнейшим хочу еще один dropdown добавить, из-за этого условие еще станет невозможный всех описывать. Как справиться с одним запросом без условии даже если параметры пустые?

---

понимаете условие if if( $maincatalog != NULL ) могут иметь много комбинации из за этого у меня получается много условии типа так

```
if($maincatalog == "" && $listproduct == "" && $q == ""){
$query = "all empty";
} elseif($maincatalog == "" && $listproduct != "" && $q == ""){
 $query = Addproduct::find()->where(['product' => $listproduct])-          >andWhere(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();
} elseif($maincatalog != "" && $listproduct == "" && $q == "") {
$query = Addproduct::find()->where(['catalog' => $maincatalog])-    >andWhere(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();
} elseif($maincatalog == "" && $listproduct == "" && $q != "") {
    $query = Addproduct::find()->where(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();
} elseif($maincatalog == "" && $listproduct != "" && $q != "") {
$query = Addproduct::find()->where(['product' => $listproduct])->andWhere(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();
} elseif($maincatalog != "" && $listproduct == "" && $q != "") {
    $query = Addproduct::find()->where(['catalog' => $maincatalog])-    >andWhere(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();
} else {
    $query = Addproduct::find()->where(['catalog' => $maincatalog])-    >andWhere(['product' => $listproduct])->andWhere(['like', 'titleru', $q])-    >all();
}
```

в дальнейшим хочу еще один dropdown добавить из за этого условие еще станет невозможный всех описывать
Как справиться с одним запросом без условии даже если параметры пустые?

---

Это модель для поиска

namespace common\models;
use yii\base\Model;

class SearchForm extends Model
{

```
public  $q;
public  $listproduct;
public  $maincatalog;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['q', 'string'],
        ['listproduct', 'string'],
        ['maincatalog', 'string']
    ];
}
```

}

---

Yii2 ActiveRecord Как разбить запрос по необходимости - Yii/Yii2
Такой запрос
$query = Addproduct::find()->where(['tip' => $tip])->andWhere(['product' => $listproduct])->andWhere(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();

можно ли как то так разбить:
$query = Addproduct::find();

if ($maincatalog != NULL)
$query->where(['catalog' => $maincatalog]);

if ($listproduct != NULL)
$query->andWhere(['product' => $listproduct]);

$query->andWhere(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();

или через andFilterWhere так:

$query = Addproduct::find()->where('***');

$query->andFilterWhere(['catalog' => $maincatalog]);

$query->all();
я пробовал оба варианта но не работает

---

```
    $query = Addproduct::find();

    if ($maincatalog != NULL)
        $query->where(['catalog' => $maincatalog]);

    if ($listproduct != NULL)
        $query->andWhere(['product' => $listproduct]);


    $query->andWhere(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();
```

этот код не работает почему?

Comment: Доброе утро. Запрос для поисковой модели? Если да, то покажите полностью код модели.

Comment: Добавте в вопрос все ваши "ответы" кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/819071/edit), ели они относятся к текущему вопросу, если нет - задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Вы так и не показали полный код модели и контроллера. Что, тяжело это сделать?

Comment: @slo_nik Если вы переносите что-то в вопрос извне, то указывайте это явно в комментарии к правке.

Answer (score -1):

Не обязательно записывать запрос в одну строку, можно разбить на несколько, добавив нужные Вам условия. Состояние $query от этого не "обнулится"

```
$query = Addproduct::find();

    if ( $maincatalog != NULL )
        $query->where(['catalog' => $maincatalog]);


    $query->andWhere(['product' => $listproduct])
          ->andWhere(['like', 'titleru', $q])->all();
```

Comment: у меня вот 3 параметра как по вашему через условии разбить запрос? $q, $listproduct, $maincatalog

Comment: @Proger точно так же как и $maincatalog

Answer (score -1):

Если Вы хотите организовать поиск по таблице, из Вашего вопроса это не до конца понятно, то Просто сгенерируйте поискову модель при помощи gii.

Есть такая штука как [yii\db\ActiveQuery::andFilterWhere()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-querytrait#andFilterWhere()-detail). Так вот, этот публичный метод добавляет дополнительное условие WHERE к существующему, но игнорирует пустые операнды.

Исходя из этого Ваш запрос превращается в следующее.

```
$query = Addproduct::find()->where('***');

$query->andFilterWhere(['catalog' => $maincatalog]);

$query->all();
```

Вот как-то так.